# Check if a string is a part of another string (PHP)

Tags: php

I'd like to check if a string is equal to another string. By equal, I mean that I want to check if the second string includes the first one in order to make mysql join's in a dynamic way. (I hope I'm clear, sorry for my english...)

I've seen some functions as `strcmp()` but it only checks if it is purely equal.
It's the same as `"$var1 === $var2".`

Is there a function which can do that ? Or could you give me some leads to do that ?

Comment: Google first.then ask

Comment: @SunilPachlangia I didn't use the word "contains", that's why I didn't find the topic. Of course I went on google first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (strpos($a,'are') !== false) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

[How do I check if a string contains a specific word in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/check-if-string-contains-specific-words)